# Parametric equation for a weird trajectory in affect of gravity and magnetic field

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-gravity, charge, classical-electrodynamics

This is a question from Bangladesh Physics Olympiad:

[image: Info]

> Draw the trajectory of the charge $+q$ .Necessary  informations are given in the figure. $B$ is the magnetic 
>   field.

What I want to know is whether there is enough information to get the parametric equation for $x, y$ - co-ordinates or not?

So far, I have been only able to roughly draw the trajectory. As the instantneous radius for a moving charged particle  $r=\frac{mv}{qB}$ and the instantneous velocity of the particle is going to increase always due to gravity; the instantneous radius of the *trajectory* will increase. So, the curvature of trajectory will decrease in time.

But, I want to work out the parametric equation for the trajectory. But I don't know how to. Any hints?

Comment: This is a standard crossed electric and magnetic field problem in disguise. The constant force due to the electric field on a charged particle being replaced by the constant force due a gravitational field.  Have a look at https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/337968/104696 So in a roundabout way this is really a duplicate?

Comment: Hi Mockingbird. I'm afraid this runs afoul of our *homework and exercises* policy (or at least the *exercises* bit of it). The vertical motion is just the usual motion under gravity and the horizontal motion is due to the Lorentz force.

Comment: @John Rennie Are yous sure about it

Comment: @Mockingbird Yes

Comment: I agree with John Rennie : you are asking us to show you how to solve a problem, rather than asking about a conceptual difficulty which you have encountered. This makes your question *off topic*. ... I agree with Farcher about the shape of the trajectory.

Comment: All I asked is hints. Not the whole answer.